# Does json have intellisense support for proto files? - c#

Tags: c#, json, protocol-buffers, proto

I have a proto file with me. Now, I have an option to save this in binary format or convert it to json format and store it.

My main thing is I want the user who will use the schema to have intellisense support when typing these files. Would json support the intellisense based on the schema ?

Comment: [Link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json)

Comment: @JohnWu I saw but not able to understand how to add intellisense for my schema file when I try to add things in json.

Comment: Hi, Were you able to figure this one? I want to do a similar thing for my project and trying to find how to do it.